# Paginator doesn't override pagination settings

Tags: hugo

I'm using hugo 0.73.0, and the Paginator doesn't seem to override the global paginate value.

**Question 1:**

In my config.toml

```
paginate = 4
```

In my list template

```
 {{ range (.Paginator 2).Pages  -}}
 {{ partial "listing.html" .}}
 {{- end }}
```

Here I want to use 2 post per page but it still shows 4 as defined by the global setting in config.

**Question 2:**
When I try

```
{ range sort (.Paginate (.Site.Taxonomies.tags.Alphabetical)).Pages.ByTitle  -}}
{{ partial "listing.html" .}}
{{- end }}
```

The list sorts my posts by name. But as soon as pagination kicks in, it messes up the sorting order. Eg. If I have 4 posts (A, B, C, D) and paginate is set to 3. then the pages are like this:

page 1: posts B, C, D

page 2: posts A

**What I want is something like this**

page 1: posts A, B, C

page 2: posts D

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The [`gohugo-theme-ananke`](https://themes.gohugo.io//theme/gohugo-theme-ananke/post/) shows 3 articles per pages, using [`layouts/posts/list.html`](https://github.com/wikty/hugo-ananke-ext/blob/32b19d80444b0edfa0f104418020afd4d7e13d32/layouts/posts/list.html) with:

```
{{ $paginator := .Paginate (where .Data.Pages "Section" .Section)}}
```

Check if overriding the Paginate option would work in that theme example site, for testing.
Then you can try and integrate `.Site.Taxonomies.tags.Alphabetical`